# Our Cocoapods library page is redirected to github page

Tags: cocoapods

I created a new pod, and pushed it to cocoapods by issuing command,

```
pod trunk push AIQKit.podspec
```

After a while, I go to cocoapods.org, can find it by searching AIQKit. but when I tried access 
https://cocoapods.org/pods/AIQKit
I was always redirected to github page even after I updated 4 versions in cocoapods.

**Report**

**1. What did you do**?

```
Then release our library by issuing command below,

$> git add -A && git commit -m "Release 0.9.4"

$> git tag '0.9.4'

$> git push --tags

$> pod lib lint AIQKit.podspec

$> pod trunk push AIQKit.podspec

then I got output,

 Congrats

 AIQKit (0.9.4) successfully published
 February 5th, 09:48
 https://cocoapods.org/pods/AIQKit
 Tell your friends!
```

**2. What did you expect to happen**?

When I access AIQKit page,
https://cocoapods.org/pods/AIQKit

I should see page for it.

**3. What happened instead**?

But reality is that I was redirected to github page
https://github.com/iqnect-org/aiqkit-ios

I can find the AIQKit from cocoapods page search, and I can use AIQKit by adding AIQKit into Podfile

**4. CocoaPods Environment**

    `Stack
       CocoaPods : 1.4.0
            Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
        RubyGems : 2.5.2
            Host : Mac OS X 10.13.3 (17D102)
           Xcode : 9.2 (9C40b)
             Git : git version 2.15.1
    Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
    Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 713cb9c62547df8651141d41b306b6c42c182fdd
    Installation Source
    Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
    Plugins
    cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
    cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
    cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
    Project that demonstrates the issue
    https://github.com/iqnect-org/aiqkit-ios`

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem was solved just correct all compiler error. So just make sure there is no any compiler error in example project before you publish